# getExternalStorageDirectory return phone storage - not sdcard

Tags: java, android

Hello this (getExternalStorageDirectory) return phone storage. How to get phone storage **AND** SDCARD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Open External Storage directory(sdcard) for storing file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file)

Answer (score 2):

Take note of this text in the getExternalStorageDirectory [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29):

*<...>Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage <...>*

There are number of answers to your question about access to the secondary sdcard, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)