# External SD card path in android version 4.0+ to read files

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am developing an android app to read video files from the external SD card to perform some function on them. To test my code, I have tried to hardcode the path of SD card like,

> File file = new File("/storage/632E-1AFA/Champion.mp4");

But now I want to make this app run on multiple devices. So I want a universal method to get the external SD card path. I have tried the **getExternalStorageDirectory** method but it points to the internal storage of the phone. The **getExternalFilesDir** points to your internal application files.

I have also tried the **System.getenv()** method with the help of - 
[Android Open External Storage directory(sdcard) for storing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file) and [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location) but it is returning a null path when I tried to debug the code.

My app includes both the read and write permissions for external storage:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

I am testing my app on Android 6.0, so I have included the run-time permissions as well. Please if someone could help me find a method or an approach that would get the path of an external sd card to run on multipe mobile devices, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at getExternalFilesDirs(). If it returns two paths then the second is on the card.

Comment: The getExternalFilesDirs() call requires minimum API level 19 (Android 4.4) and I want for a minimum API level 14 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Find some helpful methods below :

To gets the external SD path.
     /*
     * @return the external SD path
     */

```
public String getExternalSDPath() {
    StorageVolume sv = new StorageHelper().getStorage(StorageVolume.Type.EXTERNAL);
    if (sv != null) {
        return sv.file.getPath();
    } else {
        String sdpath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
        if (sdpath == null || sdpath.isEmpty()) {
            sdpath = "/storage/extSdCard";
        }

        return sdpath;
    }
}
```

/**
     * Gets the internal SD path.
     *
     * @return the internal SD path
     */

```
public String getInternalSDPath() {
    String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    return sdpath;
}
```

/**
     * External SD available.
     *
     * @return true, if successful
     */

```
public boolean externalSDAvailable() {
    String path = getExternalSDPath();
    if (path != null) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file != null && file.exists() && file.list() != null) {
            return true && isExternalSDAvailable;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

StorageHelper.java Class :

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Map.Entry;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 import android.os.Environment;

 // TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc
 /**
 * The Class StorageHelper.
 */

 public final class StorageHelper {

// private static final String TAG = "StorageHelper";

/**
 * Instantiates a new storage helper.
 */
public StorageHelper() {
}

/** The Constant STORAGES_ROOT. */
private static final String STORAGES_ROOT;

static {
    final String primaryStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    final int index = primaryStoragePath.indexOf(File.separatorChar, 1);
    if (index != -1) {
        STORAGES_ROOT = primaryStoragePath.substring(0, index + 1);
    } else {
        STORAGES_ROOT = File.separator;
    }
}

/** The Constant AVOIDED_DEVICES. */
private static final String[] AVOIDED_DEVICES = new String[] { "rootfs", "tmpfs", "dvpts", "proc", "sysfs",
        "none" };

/** The Constant AVOIDED_DIRECTORIES. */
private static final String[] AVOIDED_DIRECTORIES = new String[] { "obb", "asec" };

/** The Constant DISALLOWED_FILESYSTEMS. */
private static final String[] DISALLOWED_FILESYSTEMS = new String[] { "tmpfs", "rootfs", "romfs", "devpts", "sysfs",
        "proc", "cgroup", "debugfs" };

/**
 * Returns a list of mounted {@link StorageVolume}s Returned list always
 * includes a {@link StorageVolume} for
 * {@link Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()}.
 *
 * @param includeUsb            if true, will include USB storages
 * @return list of mounted {@link StorageVolume}s
 */
public  List<StorageVolume> getStorages(final boolean includeUsb) {
    final Map<String, List<StorageVolume>> deviceVolumeMap = new HashMap<String, List<StorageVolume>>();

    // this approach considers that all storages are mounted in the same
    // non-root directory
    if (!STORAGES_ROOT.equals(File.separator)) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/mounts"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Log.d(TAG, line);
                final StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

                final String device = tokens.nextToken();
                // skipped devices that are not sdcard for sure
                if (arrayContains(AVOIDED_DEVICES, device)) {
                    continue;
                }

                // should be mounted in the same directory to which
                // the primary external storage was mounted
                final String path = tokens.nextToken();
                if (!path.startsWith(STORAGES_ROOT)) {
                    continue;
                }

                // skip directories that indicate tha volume is not a
                // storage volume
                if (pathContainsDir(path, AVOIDED_DIRECTORIES)) {
                    continue;
                }

                final String fileSystem = tokens.nextToken();
                // don't add ones with non-supported filesystems
                if (arrayContains(DISALLOWED_FILESYSTEMS, fileSystem)) {
                    continue;
                }

                final File file = new File(path);
                // skip volumes that are not accessible
                if (!file.canRead() || !file.canExecute()) {
                    continue;
                }

                List<StorageVolume> volumes = deviceVolumeMap.get(device);
                if (volumes == null) {
                    volumes = new ArrayList<StorageVolume>(3);
                    deviceVolumeMap.put(device, volumes);
                }

                final StorageVolume volume = new StorageVolume(device, file, fileSystem);
                final StringTokenizer flags = new StringTokenizer(tokens.nextToken(), ",");
                while (flags.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    final String token = flags.nextToken();
                    if (token.equals("rw")) {
                        volume.mReadOnly = false;
                        break;
                    } else if (token.equals("ro")) {
                        volume.mReadOnly = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                volumes.add(volume);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // ignored
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // remove volumes that are the same devices
    boolean primaryStorageIncluded = false;
    final File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final List<StorageVolume> volumeList = new ArrayList<StorageVolume>();
    for (final Entry<String, List<StorageVolume>> entry : deviceVolumeMap.entrySet()) {
        final List<StorageVolume> volumes = entry.getValue();
        if (volumes.size() == 1) {
            // go ahead and add
            final StorageVolume v = volumes.get(0);
            final boolean isPrimaryStorage = v.file.equals(externalStorage);
            primaryStorageIncluded |= isPrimaryStorage;
            setTypeAndAdd(volumeList, v, includeUsb, isPrimaryStorage);
            continue;
        }
        final int volumesLength = volumes.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < volumesLength; i++) {
            final StorageVolume v = volumes.get(i);
            if (v.file.equals(externalStorage)) {
                primaryStorageIncluded = true;
                // add as external storage and continue
                setTypeAndAdd(volumeList, v, includeUsb, true);
                break;
            }
            // if that was the last one and it's not the default external
            // storage then add it as is
            if (i == volumesLength - 1) {
                setTypeAndAdd(volumeList, v, includeUsb, false);
            }
        }
    }
    // add primary storage if it was not found
    if (!primaryStorageIncluded) {
        final StorageVolume defaultExternalStorage = new StorageVolume("", externalStorage, "UNKNOWN");
        defaultExternalStorage.mEmulated = Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated();
        defaultExternalStorage.mType = defaultExternalStorage.mEmulated ? StorageVolume.Type.INTERNAL
                : StorageVolume.Type.EXTERNAL;
        defaultExternalStorage.mRemovable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
        defaultExternalStorage.mReadOnly = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY);
        volumeList.add(0, defaultExternalStorage);
    }
    return volumeList;
}

/**
 * Gets the storage.
 *
 * @param type the type
 * @return the storage
 */
public  StorageVolume getStorage(StorageVolume.Type type) {
    List<StorageVolume> list_second = getStorages(false);
    for (Iterator<StorageVolume> iterator = list_second.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        StorageVolume storageVolume = (StorageVolume) iterator.next();
        if (storageVolume.mType == type) {
            boolean e = storageVolume.file != null && storageVolume.file.exists()
                    && storageVolume.file.list() != null;
            if (e) {
                return storageVolume;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Sets {@link StorageVolume.Type}, removable and emulated flags and adds to
 * volumeList
 * 
 * @param volumeList
 *            List to add volume to
 * @param v
 *            volume to add to list
 * @param includeUsb
 *            if false, volume with type {@link StorageVolume.Type#USB} will
 *            not be added
 * @param asFirstItem
 *            if true, adds the volume at the beginning of the volumeList
 */
private  void setTypeAndAdd(final List<StorageVolume> volumeList, final StorageVolume v,
        final boolean includeUsb, final boolean asFirstItem) {
    final StorageVolume.Type type = resolveType(v);
    if (includeUsb || type != StorageVolume.Type.USB) {
        v.mType = type;
        if (v.file.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())) {
            v.mRemovable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
        } else {
            v.mRemovable = type != StorageVolume.Type.INTERNAL;
        }
        v.mEmulated = type == StorageVolume.Type.INTERNAL;
        if (asFirstItem) {
            volumeList.add(0, v);
        } else {
            volumeList.add(v);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Resolved {@link StorageVolume} type.
 *
 * @param v            {@link StorageVolume} to resolve type for
 * @return {@link StorageVolume} type
 */
private  StorageVolume.Type resolveType(final StorageVolume v) {
    if (v.file.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) && Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated()) {
        return StorageVolume.Type.INTERNAL;
    } else if (containsIgnoreCase(v.file.getAbsolutePath(), "usb")) {
        return StorageVolume.Type.USB;
    } else {
        return StorageVolume.Type.EXTERNAL;
    }
}

/**
 * Checks whether the array contains object.
 *
 * @param <T> the generic type
 * @param array            Array to check
 * @param object            Object to find
 * @return true, if the given array contains the object
 */
private  <T> boolean arrayContains(T[] array, T object) {
    for (final T item : array) {
        if (item.equals(object)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the path contains one of the directories
 * 
 * For example, if path is /one/two, it returns true input is "one" or
 * "two". Will return false if the input is one of "one/two", "/one" or
 * "/two"
 * 
 * @param path
 *            path to check for a directory
 * @param dirs
 *            directories to find
 * @return true, if the path contains one of the directories
 */
private  boolean pathContainsDir(final String path, final String[] dirs) {
    final StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(path, File.separator);
    while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String next = tokens.nextToken();
        for (final String dir : dirs) {
            if (next.equals(dir)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks ifString contains a search String irrespective of case, handling.
 * Case-insensitivity is defined as by
 * {@link String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)}.
 * 
 * @param str
 *            the String to check, may be null
 * @param searchStr
 *            the String to find, may be null
 * @return true if the String contains the search String irrespective of
 *         case or false if not or {@code null} string input
 */
public  boolean containsIgnoreCase(final String str, final String searchStr) {
    if (str == null || searchStr == null) {
        return false;
    }
    final int len = searchStr.length();
    final int max = str.length() - len;
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        if (str.regionMatches(true, i, searchStr, 0, len)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Represents storage volume information.
 */
public static  final class StorageVolume {

    /**
     * Represents {@link StorageVolume} type.
     */
    public enum Type {
        /**
         * Device built-in internal storage. Probably points to
         * {@link Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()}
         */
        INTERNAL,

        /**
         * External storage. Probably removable, if no other
         * {@link StorageVolume} of type {@link #INTERNAL} is returned by
         * {@link StorageHelper#getStorages(boolean)}, this might be
         * pointing to {@link Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()}
         */
        EXTERNAL,

        /** Removable usb storage. */
        USB
    }

    /** Device name. */
    public final String device;

    /** Points to mount point of this device. */
    public final File file;

    /** File system of this device. */
    public final String fileSystem;

    /** if true, the storage is mounted as read-only. */
    private boolean mReadOnly;

    /** If true, the storage is removable. */
    private boolean mRemovable;

    /** If true, the storage is emulated. */
    private boolean mEmulated;

    /** Type of this storage. */
    private Type mType;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new storage volume.
     *
     * @param device the device
     * @param file the file
     * @param fileSystem the file system
     */
    StorageVolume(String device, File file, String fileSystem) {
        this.device = device;
        this.file = file;
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    /**
     * Returns type of this storage.
     *
     * @return Type of this storage
     */
    public Type getType() {
        return mType;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this storage is removable.
     *
     * @return true if this storage is removable
     */
    public boolean isRemovable() {
        return mRemovable;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this storage is emulated.
     *
     * @return true if this storage is emulated
     */
    public boolean isEmulated() {
        return mEmulated;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this storage is mounted as read-only.
     *
     * @return true if this storage is mounted as read-only
     */
    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return mReadOnly;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((file == null) ? 0 : file.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the other object is StorageHelper and it's
     * {@link #file} matches this one's.
     *
     * @param obj the obj
     * @return true, if successful
     * @see Object#equals(Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final StorageVolume other = (StorageVolume) obj;
        if (file == null) {
            return other.file == null;
        }
        return file.equals(other.file);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return file.getAbsolutePath() + (mReadOnly ? " ro " : " rw ") + mType + (mRemovable ? " R " : "")
                + (mEmulated ? " E " : "") + fileSystem;
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

This path goes straight to your app directory:

```
public String getPathToAppFolder(){
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/Files/";
        }
```

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() will give you that path.

Comment: `"/Files/"`. Typo? That should be /files/.

Comment: @greenapps Why should it? Have you made bad experiences? No? So whats the problem?