# How to select location in removable SD card in Android?

Tags: android

[image: How to select SD card location to save video]

Hi I am facing a problem to choose the location in external SD card.
Some app like **ShareIt** using the below concept (See Image).
How to open this in Android.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Start an intent with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: Hi .It give an exception Activity not found.

Comment: What is 'it'? You think you dont have to post your code if you have problems? Put the used code in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: And on which Android version did you try?

Comment: i used 6.0 Marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

have you added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

above lines in your manifest

have a look through the link [Android_Open_External_Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file)