# How to make Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() create a path to SD card, not to emulated/0 which is internal memory?

Tags: java, android, android-storage

I creating a folder and putting a file in that folder using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. But it's creating a folder path to a place called `/storage/emulated/0`. I searched on the SD card for my file name, but there was any. So I determined that `/storage/emulated/0` is a placed in the phone's internal memory. But according to [Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#InternalVsExternalStorage), external memory means SD card.

For example, screenshots are stored on the SD card and I can find it by going to the Android "Download" App->SD card->Pictures->Screenshots:

[image].

Here are my code, the way I am creating a folder path and then create a unique file path for individual photo by appending the time at which the photo is stored:

```
public File getPublicDir() {
// Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"collage");
if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e("PUBLIC DIRECTORY", "Directory not created");
}
return file;
}

try{
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdformat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_HH:mm:ss");
String DateString=sdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
file=new File(getPublicDir(),"mySnapshot_"+DateString+".png");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
Boolean success=snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Compress? 
  :"+file,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NOT SAVED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**EDIT**:

I try `String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");` but `secStore` is null when I run the app. This is from [this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949650/9964100).

I try manually typed in the folder address that leads to the SD card (in the picture above):

```
String dir="/document/3464-6161:collage";
file=new File(dir,"mySnapshot_"+DateString+".png");
```

But it gives me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access external SD card by using [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment) and providing [Request permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for [Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Alternatively, you can use [StorageManager.getStorageVolumes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html#getStorageVolumes()) to know what are the available volumes available in the device. 
It will return information about [StorageVolume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume) like SD card and USB.

Note: it's available from API 24.

Using this you can access the file path you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() still gives me /storage/emulated/0

Comment: @joe doe did it help?

Comment: What did you add? I cannot see.

Comment: @joedoe I added information about StorageManager.getStorageVolumes