# Why new folder creates in Internal Storage instead of External Storage?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-storage

I tries to create a new folder in External storage SD Card. Using this code:

```
val folderMain = "NewFolder"
val f = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderMain)

if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs()
}
```

and this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But after executing this code It creates a new folder in Internal storage. Here is the screenshot of Internal Storage:

[image]

While External Storage has no new folder in it. Here is the screenshot of External Storage:

[image]

What should I do? I want to create a new folder in External storage By using Kotlin or java codes.

Comment: Do not get confused with the word "external".

Comment: I want to create a new folder in memory card. What code should I use.

Comment: Why do you ask a different question in the title than in the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Open External Storage directory(sdcard) for storing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file)

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.