# Saving a file in sdcard0 and sdcard1 android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to give an option to the user to store a video file in sdcard0(internal memory) or sdcard1. How can I do that. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and Environment.getExternalPublicStorageDirectory() will save the file in sdcard1. How can I save a file in sdcard0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466753/storing-a-file-on-internal-and-external-sdcard

Comment: That solution didnt help me. He is hardcoding the path. I dont want to hardcode the path as the path can vary in different devices

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                    Log.d("Path ------ ", " " + sdcard_path);
                    // create a File object for the parent directory
                    File PapersDiractory = new File(sdcard_path + "/Exam Papers/");
                    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
                    PapersDiractory.mkdirs();
                    // create a File object for the output file
                    File outputFile = new File(PapersDiractory, "five-point-someone-chetan-bhagat_ebook.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(
                getApplicationContext());
        File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myInternalFile = new File(directory, filename);
try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myInternalFile); // save
            fos.write(myInputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myInputText.setText("");
        responseText.setText("Saved to Internal Storage.(StorageFile.txt)");
```