# Get External SDCard Location in Android

Tags: android

I have an app with huge data pre-stored in the SD Card.

We are supporting all tablets **ICS onwards**. I am not able to find a way to access the SDCard location correctly on ALL devices.

I looked at various solutions given here on SO but they do not seem to work in all cases. Looking for a generic solution.

Even if anyone can tell me all the possible mount points of SDCard.

I am targeting android tablets only if that can narrow down the solution.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. check the topic under Using the External Storage if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan : I have tried the methods given there but they do not seem to work everywhere. In most tablets it returns /mnt/sdcard which is not the sdcard location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637935/a-safe-path-to-external-storage/16638064#16638064. i would not recommend the solution in the link. you can give it a try but i suggest you follow the docs.

Comment: @Raghunandan I will give the answer a try. In the docs they are asking to use getExternalStorageDirectory() with which I did not have a good experience. It works on Micromax tablets but not on beyond and ambrane (Chinese tablet based) and also does not work on Samsung galaxy tabs.

Comment: it will give the path of external storage. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory(). check the note under the `public static File getExternalStorageDirectory ()`. **Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage.**

Comment: @Raghunandan Ok. That makes sense. But even in your answer you posted some devices do act as exceptions right? I mean getExternalStorageDirectory might give internal storage when external storage is present. Am I right?

Comment: i too had the same confusion. i got it cleared when i was looking at one of the answers by commonsware. The solution is not recommended and may not work well on devices. I haven't tested that on all devices. If you wish to use it. go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: Can you clarify? How do you load this "huge data pre-stored in the SD Card"? Do you mean it's an external SD card?

Comment: @andy256 : I give the clients the SD Card which they can use in their tablets using my app.

Comment: Doh! It's in the title :-) Seems to me that we cannot absolutely guarantee a solution. I recommend @Raghunandan advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a common problem due to the fact that Android devices are highly fragmented. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refers to whatever the device manufacturer considers to be "external storage". On some devices, this is removable media, like an SD card. On some devices, this is a portion of on-device flash.(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())  Here, "external storage" means "the drive accessible via USB Mass Storage mode when mounted on a host machine". 
If a device manufacturer has elected to have external storage be on-board flash and also has an SD card, you will need to contact that manufacturer to determine whether or not you can use the SD card. For most conforming android devices(known ones from google compliance list) the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` should work. Or you could write a custom storage class that looks at the mount points and gives you the right path to the mounted SDCard. This is something I've implemented and it has worked so far.

```
public class StorageOptions {
    private static ArrayList<String> mMounts = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<String> mVold = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static String[] labels;
    public static String[] paths;
    public static int count = 0;
    private static final String TAG = StorageOptions.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void determineStorageOptions() {
        readMountsFile();

        readVoldFile();

        compareMountsWithVold();

        testAndCleanMountsList();

        setProperties();
    }

    private static void readMountsFile() {
        /*
         * Scan the /proc/mounts file and look for lines like this:
         * /dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/sdcard vfat
         * rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,
         * relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0602,dmask
         * =0602,allow_utime=0020,codepage
         * =cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
         * 
         * When one is found, split it into its elements and then pull out the
         * path to the that mount point and add it to the arraylist
         */

        // some mount files don't list the default
        // path first, so we add it here to
        // ensure that it is first in our list
        mMounts.add("/mnt/sdcard");

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/proc/mounts"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("/dev/block/vold/")) {
                    String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
                    String element = lineElements[1];

                    // don't add the default mount path
                    // it's already in the list.
                    if (!element.equals("/mnt/sdcard"))
                        mMounts.add(element);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void readVoldFile() {
        /*
         * Scan the /system/etc/vold.fstab file and look for lines like this:
         * dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard 1
         * /devices/platform/s3c-sdhci.0/mmc_host/mmc0
         * 
         * When one is found, split it into its elements and then pull out the
         * path to the that mount point and add it to the arraylist
         */

        // some devices are missing the vold file entirely
        // so we add a path here to make sure the list always
        // includes the path to the first sdcard, whether real
        // or emulated.
        mVold.add("/mnt/sdcard");

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                    String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
                    String element = lineElements[2];

                    if (element.contains(":"))
                        element = element.substring(0, element.indexOf(":"));

                    // don't add the default vold path
                    // it's already in the list.
                    if (!element.equals("/mnt/sdcard"))
                        mVold.add(element);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void compareMountsWithVold() {
        /*
         * Sometimes the two lists of mount points will be different. We only
         * want those mount points that are in both list.
         * 
         * Compare the two lists together and remove items that are not in both
         * lists.
         */

        for (int i = 0; i < mMounts.size(); i++) {
            String mount = mMounts.get(i);
            if (!mVold.contains(mount))
                mMounts.remove(i--);
        }

        // don't need this anymore, clear the vold list to reduce memory
        // use and to prepare it for the next time it's needed.
        mVold.clear();
    }

    private static void testAndCleanMountsList() {
        /*
         * Now that we have a cleaned list of mount paths Test each one to make
         * sure it's a valid and available path. If it is not, remove it from
         * the list.
         */

        for (int i = 0; i < mMounts.size(); i++) {
            String mount = mMounts.get(i);
            File root = new File(mount);
            if (!root.exists() || !root.isDirectory() || !root.canWrite())
                mMounts.remove(i--);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void setProperties() {
        /*
         * At this point all the paths in the list should be valid. Build the
         * public properties.
         */
        Constants.mMounts = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        int j = 0;
        if (mMounts.size() > 0) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
                mLabels.add("Auto");
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
                    mLabels.add("External SD Card 1");
                    j = 1;
                } else
                    mLabels.add("Internal Storage");
            } else {
                if (!Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()
                        || Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated())
                    mLabels.add("Internal Storage");
                else {
                    mLabels.add("External SD Card 1");
                    j = 1;
                }
            }

            if (mMounts.size() > 1) {
                for (int i = 1; i < mMounts.size(); i++) {
                    mLabels.add("External SD Card " + (i + j));
                }
            }
        }

        labels = new String[mLabels.size()];
        mLabels.toArray(labels);

        paths = new String[mMounts.size()];
        mMounts.toArray(paths);
        Constants.mMounts = (ArrayList<String>) mMounts.clone();
        Constants.mLabels = (ArrayList<String>) mLabels.clone();
        count = Math.min(labels.length, paths.length);

        // don't need this anymore, clear the mounts list to reduce memory
        // use and to prepare it for the next time it's needed.
        mMounts.clear();

    }
}
```

I found this off of a similar question from SO, that I dont have the link to unfortunately, but it s there on probably Sony's Android developer site(no links there either unfortunately).  Wagic - a C++ game engine library implements the same and their code is here: http://wagic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4300/trunk/projects/mtg/Android/src/net/wagic/utils/StorageOptions.java
so you could look at the implementation. I wish someone from Google can answer this question and provide a single way that reads the SDcard mount point from all Android devices

Comment: Just one doubt. From where to get Constants.mMounts ?

Comment: Oh sorry that is my implementation specific class - a class that holds all app constants, not necessary for you, you could implement your own

Comment: It seems it does not take into account tabs with /mnt/extsd :(

Comment: It actually should return a hash of all possible cards. If it doesnt then unfortunately you have to identify it and hardcode if you want to make a truly global android app that can be used on tablets like Chinese tablets that use this extsd notation

Comment: Indeed this does not find secondary mounts like a mounted SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Its not simple as you are thinking,
String f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
Log.v("TAG",f);//to print the path of sdcard

It returns device storage path not an external sdcard path.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get the path to the SD card use this code

`String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`

Then use this to get the path of the specific folder/file

`String path  = baseDir + "/your folder(s)/" + fileName;`

Comment: This is not valid in ALL devices.

Answer (score -6):

Its simple.

```
String f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
Log.v("TAG",f);//to print the path of sdcard
```

if you want to access a file then.

```
String f =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/file.ext";
Log.v("TAG",f);//to print the path of file in Logcat.
```

Comment: please provide a link to documentation or tutorial and make sure you've answered the question "for ALL devices"

Comment: It simply does not return the path to the *external* sd card.

Comment: This answer that does not address the main issueof the question, being "Get path to External SDCard in ALL android devices".