# Class will not write to my SD card

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, android-viewpager

```
package com.adamschardt.hauling;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    private class MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         Fragment tmpFragment;
         if(position==4){
          tmpFragment = new SlidePageSupportFragment4();
         }else{
          tmpFragment = new SlidePageSupportFragment();
             ((SlidePageSupportFragment)tmpFragment).setPageNumber(position);
         }
            return tmpFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

      EditText fcontent,fcontent2,fcontent3,fcontent4,fname;
      Button write;
      protected void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_page);
        fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        fcontent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        fcontent2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        fcontent3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit3);
        fcontent4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit4);
        write = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnwrite);

            write.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String filename = fname.getText().toString();
        String filecontent = fcontent.getText().toString();
        String filecontent2 = fcontent2.getText().toString();
        String filecontent3 = fcontent3.getText().toString();
        String filecontent4 = fcontent4.getText().toString();

        FileOperations fop = new FileOperations();
        fop.write(filename, filecontent, filecontent2, filecontent3, filecontent4, filecontent4);
        if(fop.write(filename, filecontent, filecontent2, filecontent3, filecontent4, filecontent4)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename+".txt created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I/O error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
      });


      }
      }
```

I cannot write to my sd card. In fact the write button doesnt do anything. Did I initiate it properly? Is my code wrong? My logcat isnt any help either :/ Any help would be appreciated

I am not sure if it is because i am using view pager?

Comment: Your code may be correct but for now, you have set security permissions in AndroidManifest, simply Google it :-)

Comment: I think your Android file I/O operations is not proper for SD card. Perhaps upload your class FileOperations. Later I'll post an answer that I think will help you. Keep posted to your progress.

Comment: If you think your problem may be in SD or file I/O, then add another (more proper) tag to your question, and remove android-fragments as the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add SD permission to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: ya i have read and write permissions set. Usually if you forget those your app crashes. my button literately does nothing even though it is set.

Answer (score 0):

I have done SD card processing before, and it's not trivial. Start with the basics at [Environment class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) . A good Stackoverflow is [Get External SD Location][2]

[2]: [Get External SDCard Location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050388/get-external-sdcard-location-in-android) .

An example for my issue is with the Samsung phone, the SD resides at "/storage/extSdCard/". So there may be issues of the manufacturer.

Good luck...